# Always use private key authentication for scp

Tags: ssh, scp, private-key, password-prompt

I'm using scp in a script, which normally should always use private key authentication. If for some reason the private key is missing, I want the script to fail rather than display a password prompt.

Is it possible to disable this prompt, or to somehow specify that private key authentication should always be used?

Comment: I've done something similar to what you're describing by using an `expect` script. I don't have that handy, but expect isn't difficult to learn if you don't already know it.

Comment: `-o PreferredAuthentications=publickey`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option I was looking for is `-B`:

```
-B      Selects batch mode (prevents asking for passwords or passphrases).
```